# How do I manipulate a JSON object returned by AJAX?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, json

I have this jQuery in my Rails app:

```
  $('#rankings_link a').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      url: '/rankings',
      type: 'get'
    }).done(function(received_data){
      for (var m = 0; m < received_data.length; m++) {
        $('#rankings ol').append('<li>' + received_data[m] + '</li>');
      }
    });
  });
```

At the end of the rankings method in my controller is:

```
:render => 'json'
```

But when I click on the `#rankings_link`, it sends me to `/rankings` and displays a large block of preformatted text like this:

```
["Farag, Ali", "Harrity, Todd", ...]
```

I want to be able to put each element of (what seems to be) the array in an ordered list.  But clearly this isn't what's happening and I don't know why.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop the default action of `<a>` (which is to open the page specified by `href` attribute)

```
$('#rankings_link a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); // <- this
  // ...
});
```

Comment: but if I do that, it won't render anything since I'm appending the data on a different page.  i.e. I'm on the home page, click that link, and if I have peventDefault() in there, it won't go to the /rankings page...know what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

Try to validate your JSON before sending it to the view.

It is better if you can send some hard coded JSON first. The [Online JSON Viwer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) validates JSON in a nice way.

You can can also create the JSON manually and render it as text, jQuery will return it as JSON.

There is the `to_json` method in ActiveSupport, you can try that also.

Answer (score 0):

Add `:remote => true` as the link param, also make sure you have in your application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```